# R: Replacing Ranges with their Percentiles

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose, I have the following data frame:

```
var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10)
var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10)
var_3 = rnorm(100,10,10)

d = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)

head(d)


      var_1     var_2      var_3
1 14.251923 14.877801  22.636207
2  7.325137  8.513718  21.021522
3  3.400001 -3.400397  11.274797
4 16.400597  8.623980   9.366115
5  7.065583 13.155570  17.891432
6 21.297912  4.341385 -11.337330
```

**My Question:** For each element in each variable, I want to replace the element with the percentile it belongs to.

For example:

```
a = quantile(d$var_1, c( 0.15, 0.3, 0.35, 0.45, 0.5, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1))

b = quantile(d$var_2, c(0.16, 0.23, 0.65, 0.71, 0.95))

c = quantile(d$var_3, c(0.15, 0.28, 0.7, 0.73, 0.87))


> a
        5%        10%        15%        20%        25%        30%        35%        40%        45%        50%        55%        60%        65%        70%        75% 
-0.8806901  0.3595086  1.1201300  3.0581928  5.0901641  7.0056228  7.6089831  8.9853805  9.9264540 10.2235212 11.5707533 13.2422940 15.1076889 16.5354881 17.9336020 
       80%        85%        90%        95%       100% 
19.5312682 21.9264905 24.4511364 26.6820271 41.4419744 

> b
      16%       23%       65%       71%       95% 
-2.795294  1.430715 11.070815 12.688064 25.270823 

> c
      15%       28%       70%       73%       87% 
 0.958404  5.767591 15.258532 16.013648 20.467892
```

For example:

- if `d$var_2 < -2.795294`, then  `d$var_2 = 16th percentile`
- if `d$var_3 between (5.767591 , 15.258532)`, then `d$var_3 = 70th percentile`

I can write multiple "if statements" do this manually, but is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this by applying a custom function:

```
library(tidyverse)

ApplyQuantiles <- function(x, y) {
  cut(
    x,
    breaks = c(quantile(x, probs = y)),
    labels = c(names(quantile(x, probs = y))[-1]),
    include.lowest = TRUE
  )
}

output <- d %>% 
  mutate(var_1 = ApplyQuantiles(var_1, c(0, 0.15, 0.3, 0.35, 0.45, 0.5, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1)),
         var_2 = ApplyQuantiles(var_2, c(0, 0.16, 0.23, 0.65, 0.71, 0.95, 1.0)),
         var_3 = ApplyQuantiles(var_3, c(0, 0.15, 0.28, 0.7, 0.73, 0.87, 1.0))) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), str_replace, pattern = "%", replacement = "th percentile"))
```

Output

```
head(output, 10)

               var_1            var_2            var_3
1    45th percentile  95th percentile  87th percentile
2    35th percentile 100th percentile  70th percentile
3    70th percentile  95th percentile  70th percentile
4    80th percentile  65th percentile  70th percentile
5    30th percentile  16th percentile  28th percentile
6    15th percentile  95th percentile  28th percentile
7    30th percentile  16th percentile  15th percentile
8    45th percentile  16th percentile  70th percentile
9    65th percentile  95th percentile  70th percentile
10   45th percentile  65th percentile  70th percentile
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting `d`ata and `list` of `q`antile probs in `mapply` and `cut`ting in `quantile`s there.

```
q <- list(c(0.15, 0.3, 0.35, 0.45, 0.5, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1),
          c(0.16, 0.23, 0.65, 0.71, 0.95),
          c(0.15, 0.28, 0.7, 0.73, 0.87))
r <- 
  mapply(\(x, y) {y <- union(0:1, y); cut(x, quantile(x, y), labels=y[-1])}, d, q)
```

*Gives:*

```
head(as.data.frame(r))
#   var_1 var_2 var_3
# 1  0.85  0.71     1
# 2  0.15  0.71  0.28
# 3   0.5  0.16  0.73
# 4  0.65  0.95  0.87
# 5   0.5  0.23     1
# 6  0.35  0.23     1
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(var_1=rnorm(100, 10, 10), var_2=rnorm(100, 10, 10),
                var_3=rnorm(100, 10, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

With my santoku package:

```r
library(santoku)
d$q_1 <- chop_quantiles(d$var_1, 0:100/100, labels = lbl_endpoint("%s"))
d$q_2 <- chop_quantiles(d$var_2, 0:100/100, labels = lbl_endpoint("%s"))
d$q_3 <- chop_quantiles(d$var_3, 0:100/100, labels = lbl_endpoint("%s"))
```

```r
head(d)
       var_1      var_2    var_3  q_1  q_2  q_3
1 10.9747361   7.463509 24.13691 0.55 0.44  0.9
2 24.8326562 -17.530453 10.83047 0.94    0 0.54
3 12.5138699   7.945799 19.37541  0.6 0.45 0.83
4 14.1343011   2.135220  7.09554 0.65 0.24 0.35
5  4.2622584 -13.138526 27.96278 0.26 0.02 0.95
6  0.8394213   9.369224 18.18695 0.17 0.58  0.8
```

This creates factors. Using `lbl_endpoint()` gives the left hand percentile. If you leave it out, you'll get labels like `[2%-3%)`.